# PHP Switch Case Counter

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, switch-statement, case

I'm very new to PHP and I'm developing in the context of WordPress (with ACF). I'm creating a custom layout builder, I got it working but I want to make my code simpler. Right now is `14 cases` which load a `__.php` file if is applicable. Here is an example snippet:

```
switch (get_row_layout()) {

    case 'row_1' :
        include ('template_row_1.php');
    break;

    case 'row_2' :
        include ('template_row_2.php');
    break;

    case 'row_3' :
        include ('template_row_3.php');
    break;

}
```

Keep in mind I have 14 total cases (for now). They are named `row_1 --> row_14` and the templates files are also named sequentially.

Is there any way of coding this without using so many switch cases? What if I include another `row` in ACF and I want to avoid coding another switch case.

I was thinking a counter which counts the total `layouts` inside the `builder` and switch case loops through them. Does this makes sense? I just want to make my code simpler and avoid the repetitiveness of the statements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically create the name of the file to be loaded.

Something like this:

```
$row = get_row_layout();
include ('template_'.$row.'.php');
```

Comment: Thank you! That works in dynamically generating the file but part of my question is to avoid the switch case statements as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mmarquez: You can just use these 2 lines *instead* of the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy

```
include ('template_' . get_row_layout() . '.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this ?

```
 if ( get_row_layout() ){
       $str = get_row_layout();
       $file_name = 'template_' . $str . '.php';
        include( $file_name  );
    }
```